# check my proof on simple walks and circuits

Tags: graph-theory

I want to prove that if a graph has no circuits then it is simple.

Consider a walk with a repeated edge, AabBbaC, where A, B, C are strings of vertices.

**(Here I reversed the order of edge ba, because it seemed more natural from my experiences of drawing graph. Was this necessary? i.e. is it possible that in the second appearance of an edge, the vertices appear in the same order as the first?)**

Then abBba is a circuit because it has the same start and finish.
Therefore, if a graph has no circuits than it has no repeated edges.

Is this correct?

Answer (score 1):

I’m afraid not: all you’ve shown is that a walk that repeats an edge in the opposite direction contains a circuit, and this says nothing about whether the graph is simple.

Here you’d do better to try to prove the contrapositive: show that if $G$ is **not** simple, then $G$ contains a circuit. This is logically equivalent to the desired statement, and it’s very easy to prove.  If $G$ is not simple, it contains two vertices $u$ and $v$ that are connected by at least two edges, like this:

```
                ___  
               /   \  
            u o     o v  
               \___/
```

Can you find a circuit here?